# gdata for youtube brand channels returns inconsistent results

Tags: youtube-api, gdata-api

I make use of the GData YouTube api to return lists of all the videos uploaded by a user.  My query can return different results depending on which machine I run it from.  For example:

`$wget --header="X-GData-Client: XXXXX" --header="User-Agent: XXXXX YouTube-Java/1.0 GData-Java/1.41.5(gzip)" "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=fosters&orderby=published&time=all_time&client=YYY&start-index=50&max-items=25" -q -O - | xmllint --format - | grep total`

(where `XXXXX` is my api key, and `YYY` is a private identifier)

produces the result:

`<openSearch:totalResults>118</openSearch:totalResults>`

from certain locations, but from other locations:

`<openSearch:totalResults>68</openSearch:totalResults>`

The queries with the first result originate from machines located in the UK, the other result from machines located outside UK.

Is either of these numbers correct?  How can I tell which one?

Answer (score 1):

Both is correct, it show the videos which  was playable for machine's ip/country(by default if you didn't put restriction parameter). If you request

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=fosters&orderby=published&time=all_time&client=YYY&start-index=50&max-results=25&restriction=GB

The result is 118, no matter where your machine located.

One more thing, **&max-items=** should change to **&max-results=**